# Excel Powerpivot Pipes Issues

Tags: pipe, powerpivot, separator

I'm having issues with power pivot Excel 2016.

The problem is that I usually import a .csv file with pipes (vertical bar) as separators, and for the past few years I didn't had any sort of problem, but now with the same computer, same windows (10), and same Microsoft Office 2016, it won't recognise the pipe separator, and groups everything in a single column.

I know ways to workaround this but I do really wanna make it work again, and I can't find a way to do it again.

It doesn't show any error or so, just won't split data into columns

I already tried changing the encoding ANSI to UTF but nothing, also reinstalled the AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone having this trouble

i manage to solve it installing AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 (2010 and 2016) in my main language (Spanish)

the official website is: https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=13255

I hope this helps anyone with this problem